# Ggplot2: how to manually assign different colors to different factor levels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill

My factor has 2 levels: A and B

```
data_set %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = effort, y = rating, fill = factorAB)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean") + 
    scale_fill_manual(name = "factorAB", values=c("darkgoldenrod2", "chartreuse4"))
```

So I have 2 conditions on my X axis (2 effort conditions, effort 1 and effort 2), and I also have 2 factors (A and B). Scale_fill_manual function assigns color to each factor, 1 color for A and 1 color for B, but I want to assign 4 different colors (so effort 1 A is different from effort 2 A).

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: please provide data using `dput(mydata)`

Answer (score 2):

Change fill to an interaction!

```
 ggplot(aes(x = effort, y = rating, fill = interaction(factorAB,effort)))
+ ...
```